# Creating a visual pattern of a text file

Tags: python

I made a Python script that takes an input text file in binary (1 character at each line) and creates a visual pattern with it, as an image, but I need to know if there are better solutions to my methods and what can I do to optimize it.

What it does is it takes the text file, put every line in an array, create a square image based on the array length and draw each pixel of the image based on the elements of the array as either black or white, being black if the element is 0 and white if it's 1.

```
import math
from PIL import Image
import easygui as gui
import sys
def replace_last(source_string, replace_what, replace_with):
    head, _sep, tail = source_string.rpartition(replace_what)
    return head + replace_with + tail

def str2tupleList(s):
    return eval( "[%s]" % s )

t = gui.buttonbox("BinaryToPadronizedVisualCode", "BinaryToPadronizedVisualCode",["Select File", "Exit"])
if t =="Select File":
 fs = gui.fileopenbox()
 fs
else:
 sys.exit()

with open(fs, 'r') as f:
 Bin = [line.strip() for line in f]

half = int(round(math.sqrt(len(Bin))))
im = Image.new('RGB', (half, half+1))

imagem = ""
num = 0
while (num<len(Bin)):
  Bin[num]
  if Bin[num] == "0":
    b = "0, 0, 0"
  else:
    b = "255, 255, 255"
  imagem = (imagem + "(" + b + "), ")
  num += 1

imagem = replace_last(imagem, ', ', "")

im.putdata(str2tupleList(imagem))

imm = im.resize((1000,1000))
imm.save('bintoimg.jpg')
gui.msgbox("Image Saved!")
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I hope the following answer can be of service anyway.

---

It's not all bad. You're already using `with open() as`, a construct we have to teach many new users here. Some of your variable names are almost good and it's more or less straightforward what's happening. Once you run a couple of example texts and see *what* it does (I'd never heard of 'padronized' before), it's a small enough program to figure out *how* it does that.

By default, your code will produce an image of 1000x1000 pixels. If the target file is empty, a 1000x1000 black square will be generated. The size and extension are hardcoded in the program. If you want to keep the configuration in the code, it might be preferred to set the values in pseudo-constant values at the top of your file. This would make re-use of the values easier. This won't matter much now, but if you ever want to grow your program or make the values adjustable by external configuration or program arguments, you've already got the basis in place.

#### Select file

In this block:

```
if t =="Select File":
 fs = gui.fileopenbox()
 fs
```

That last `fs` isn't doing anything. `fs` is a terrible name either way, let's make it `sourcefile`, `return` it from a function and add error handling so the code doesn't try to keep running when the input is invalid (for example, when we back-out of the menu after hitting 'Select File' or if we select an image as source file).

#### Consistent quotes and whitespace

While we're at it, you use `'` single-quotes and `"` double-quotes for strings. Pick one, stick to it. Most people go with double-quotes, that way we don't have to escape every single quote that's part of an actual string. You're also using different levels of indentation, which is simply confusing. Choose an indentation (2 or 4 spaces are most common) and stick with it. Same goes for whitespace around operators. You do this in one place, yet not so in others. It's better readable if you use it everywhere.

#### Variable naming

`num`, `half`, `im` and `b` are unfortunate names.

- `num` contains an integer and the common abbreviation for an integer that doubles as an iterator is `i`. Not `num`. Luckily, we don't need it. I don't like `while` loops, so I'm going to replace it by a `for` loop. It looks better, doesn't require an intermediate variable and is less likely to accidentally not run to completion.
- `half` is always a terrible name, since it doesn't tell us what it's a half of. Does it contain half the program? Will it be set to `True` once half the program is reached? Does it contain half a problem? Half a file? Half a cookie?
- `im` in this context is probably something related to an image, but considering the entire program deals with images that doesn't help us much. Especially since further on you're using `imm` which is basically a resized `im` (you don't have to use a new variable for that, just re-use the old one like you did with `imagemem`). In other programs, `im` could be short for ['imaginary'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number).
- `b` is probably supposed to be a binary representation of something, probably of colours. The colours of a square of some kind, in RGB. Let's call it a `pixel` for now.

#### Functions

Let's combine all that, put all of your program behind functions for re-usability (besides, it makes larger programs a lot easier to follow) and put it all behind a 'main guard'.

It's a good practice to start using those, especially if you ever want to re-use parts of your code. Now your main function (your entire program) only gets executed if the script is called directly, not when it's called by `import`. This helps with re-use (it's a recurring theme) and if you ever want to write tests for your code.

#### Eval

Some would say the biggest problem with your code is your use of `eval`. There are a couple of problems with that function:

- It's slow.
- It's hard to debug, since how it functions is almost like a program of itself.

There's almost always a better alternative available.

It's also unsafe. `eval` will take almost anything and try to make something of it. Even if it's illegal or dangerous input. If you tell `eval` to throw away half your files, it will definitely try to do so. Now, your program calls it on already processed input so the damage should be small. But we don't need it. I'm not going to rewrite it though, so for now we'll borrow the approach used [on Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-to-tuple-list/). It might be good practice to try and see if you can create something similar on your own. Luckily it already has its own function, so we don't have to change anything in the rest of the program to make it work. It's one of the benefits of using functions, so use them wherever it makes sense.

#### Conclusion

If we do all that and put all of your program behind functions, it could look like this:

```
import math
from PIL import Image
import easygui as gui
import sys


IMG_SIZE = (1000,1000)
TARGET_FILENAME = "bintoimg"
TARGET_EXTENSION = ".jpg"
TARGET_FILE = TARGET_FILENAME + TARGET_EXTENSION


def replace_last(source_string, replace_what, replace_with):
    head, _sep, tail = source_string.rpartition(replace_what)
    return head + replace_with + tail

def str2tupleList(s):
    result = []
    temp = []
    for token in s.split(", "):
        num = int(token.replace("(", "").replace(")", ""))
        temp.append(num)
        if ")" in token:
          result.append(tuple(temp))
          temp = []
    return result

def ask_sourcefile():
    t = gui.buttonbox("BinaryToPadronizedVisualCode", "BinaryToPadronizedVisualCode",["Select File", "Exit"])
    if t =="Select File":
        return gui.fileopenbox()
    else:
        sys.exit()

def load_data_from_file(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        return [line.strip() for line in f]

def create_image(source):
    imagem = ""
    for line in source:
        print(line)
        if line == "0":
            pixel = "0, 0, 0"
        else:
            pixel = "255, 255, 255"
        imagem += "(" + pixel + "), "
    return str2tupleList(replace_last(imagem, ', ', ""))

def main():
    sourcefile = ask_sourcefile()
    try:
        binary_data = load_data_from_file(sourcefile)
    except:
        gui.msgbox("No file or incorrect file selected.")
        sys.exit()

    half = int(round(math.sqrt(len(binary_data))))
    image = Image.new('RGB', (half, half + 1))
    image.putdata(create_image(binary_data))
    image = image.resize(IMG_SIZE)
    image.save(TARGET_FILE)
    gui.msgbox("Image Saved!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It's still far from perfect (there's no good reason to use strings as an intermediary data here, the program could be rewritten to work purely with tuples and lists), but I think it looks a great deal better than it used to. Some of the advice I've written comes from the Python Enhancement Proposals (PEPs). You can find the index [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/) and the main style guide (PEP 8) [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).